# unable to build app on appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-cli

I am not able to build android app project on appcelerator studio.

I am using Titanium sdk 5.1.1.GA the console just stops after extracting module resources, see below:

```
[INFO] :   Encrypting JavaScript files: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\titanium_prep.win32.exe "com.test7" "C:\Users\Fatimah\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\test7\build\android\assets" "app.js" "iphone/ui/ApplicationWindowPlatform.js" "iphone/ui/Drawer.js" "ui/ApplicationWindow.js" "ui/Drawer.js" "ui/ApplicationWindowPlatform.js" "_app_props_.json"
[INFO] :   Writing C:\Users\Fatimah\Documents\Appcelerator_Studio_Workspace\test7\build\android\bin\assets\app.json
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\5.1.1.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.res.zip
```

Comment: Try doing build clean on your project and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the build would get stuck extracting the modules. Try cleaning your project, then building again. You might get lucky.

It could also be your Node.js version. We use a pretty old Node module called "adm-zip" for extracting zip files, so it's possible it's being finicky. Try using Node.js 4.x or 0.12.

Comment: updating node.js to the latest version solved the issue! Thanks load Chris! You're my life saver!